# Return value to input field by class name

Tags: javascript, html, input

So I have multiple input fields in my code which include `currency` class as following

```
<input class="form-textbox number-only currency" type="text" id="nilai1" required/>
<input class="form-textbox number-only currency" type="text" id="nilai2" required/>
```

I managed to find a javascript function to change the number format to currency

```
function formatRupiah(nominal){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID',
        { style: 'currency', currency: 'IDR', minimumFractionDigits: 0 }
    ).format(nominal);
}
```

And with this function below, I am able to show the value in console

```
$('.rupiah').keyup(function(){
    console.log(formatRupiah(this.value));
});
```

But I couldn't find a way to return the value to my input fields because I have multiple input fields with `currency` class. Is there any way to return the value by class according to which input fields the users are typing? Thank you.

Comment: well, `this` inside the callback is the input the user is typing in ... as you already know since you're already using `this.value` in that callback??? did I miss the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `this` to refer to the specific input field that triggered the event like the following way:

```js
function formatRupiah(nominal){
  return new Intl.NumberFormat('id-ID',
    { style: 'currency', currency: 'IDR', minimumFractionDigits: 0 }
  ).format(nominal);
}

$('.currency').keyup(function(){
  //get only the number
  var numericValue = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
  //check if the value is valid
  if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
    //format the numeric value as currency
    var formattedValue = formatRupiah(numericValue);
    //update the input field with the formatted value
    $(this).val(formattedValue);
  }
  else{
    //clear the input field if the value is not numreic
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-textbox number-only currency" type="text" id="nilai1" required/>
<input class="form-textbox number-only currency" type="text" id="nilai2" required/>
```

Comment: But when I typed letter instead of number, it returns RpNaN. Any clue how to avoid this to happen?